# Moving html into php

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi I am new to php and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction where I can find how to merge html file and php into one. I have an application with html page to get the information and then post it to php file to run the calculations and display them. I would like to know how can I input the information have it calculated in php and displayed at same time.

This is the code I have done so far.

**fxCalc.hmtl**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>F/X Calculator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Money Banks F/X Calculator</h1>
        <hr/><br/>
        <form name="fxCalc" action="fxCalc.php" method="post">

            <center>
                <select name="srcCucy">
                    <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
                    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                    <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
                    <option value="USD">USD</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" name="srcAmt" value="" />

                <select name="dstCucy">
                    <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
                    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                    <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
                    <option value="USD">USD</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" name="dstAmt" value="" disabled="disabled" />

                <br/><br/>

                <input type="submit" value="Convert"/>
                <input type="reset"/>
            </center>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**fxCalc.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
  require_once( 'FxDataModel.php' );

  $fxCurrencies  = fxDataModel::getFxCurrencies();



  if( is_numeric( $srcAmt ) )
  {
    $dstCucy = $_POST[ 'dstCucy' ];
    $srcCucy = $_POST[ 'srcCucy' ];

    $dstAmt = fxDataModel::getFxRate( $srcCucy, $dstCucy ) * $srcAmt;   
  }
  else
  {
    $dstAmt  = ''                ;
    $dstCucy = $fxCurrencies[ 0 ];
    $srcAmt  = ''                ;
    $srcCucy = $fxCurrencies[ 0 ];
  }
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>F/X Calculator</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 align="center">Money Banks F/X Calculator</h1>
    <hr/><br/>
    <form name="fxCalc" action="fxCalc.php" method="post">

      <center>
        <select name="srcCucy">
        <?php
          foreach( $fxCurrencies as $fxCurrency )
          {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $fxCurrency ?>"

            <?php
               if( $fxCurrency === $srcCucy )
               {
            ?>   
                selected
             <?php
               }
             ?>

            ><?php echo $fxCurrency ?></option>
        <?php
          }
        ?>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="srcAmt" value="<?php echo $srcAmt ?>"/>

        <select name="dstCucy">
        <?php
          foreach( $fxCurrencies as $fxCurrency )
          {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $fxCurrency ?>"

            <?php
               if( $fxCurrency === $dstCucy )
               {
            ?>
                selected
             <?php
               }
             ?>

            ><?php echo $fxCurrency ?></option>

        <?php
          }
        ?>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="dstAmt" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $dstAmt ?>"/>

        <br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Convert"/>
        <input type="reset"/>

      </center>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you do the same thing you did with your `select` / `options` generation ?

Comment: I would if i knew how i used examples from the book to get this far and now im stuck.

Comment: Just ensure that your html isn't wrapped in `<?php ... ?>` and it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything on the same page, remove the action in your php form and add an isset for the form submission

```
<?php
//when submit button is pressed do this
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

require_once( 'FxDataModel.php' );

$fxCurrencies  = fxDataModel::getFxCurrencies();



if( is_numeric( $srcAmt ) )
{
$dstCucy = $_POST[ 'dstCucy' ];
$srcCucy = $_POST[ 'srcCucy' ];

$dstAmt = fxDataModel::getFxRate( $srcCucy, $dstCucy ) * $srcAmt;   
}
else
{
$dstAmt  = ''                ;
$dstCucy = $fxCurrencies[ 0 ];
$srcAmt  = ''                ;
$srcCucy = $fxCurrencies[ 0 ];
}

}//end if post submit
?>


<body>
<h1 align="center">Money Banks F/X Calculator</h1>
<hr/><br/>
<form name="fxCalc" action="" method="post">

  <center>
    <select name="srcCucy">
    <?php
      foreach( $fxCurrencies as $fxCurrency )
      {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fxCurrency ?>"

        <?php
           if( $fxCurrency === $srcCucy )
           {
        ?>   
            selected
         <?php
           }
         ?>

        ><?php echo $fxCurrency ?></option>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="srcAmt" value="<?php echo $srcAmt ?>"/>

    <select name="dstCucy">
    <?php
      foreach( $fxCurrencies as $fxCurrency )
      {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fxCurrency ?>"

        <?php
           if( $fxCurrency === $dstCucy )
           {
        ?>
            selected
         <?php
           }
         ?>

        ><?php echo $fxCurrency ?></option>

    <?php
      }
    ?>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="dstAmt" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $dstAmt ?>"/>

    <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Convert"/>
    <input type="reset"/>

  </center>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Not sure what your require once is for and what other code may be interferring